# C++ Can anyone look over my complete newbie text based rpg game code?

Tags: c++, if-statement, switch-statement

I am a complete brand new coder who has had probably less than 2 weeks with c++ and taught myself a lot of if statements as well as switches.

It would be great if someone could look through this game I've been making and talk me through all the things I should and shouldn't be doing.

Note that the second trail *if statement* is not coded yet.

```
#include "MeadowGiant.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

MeadowGiant::MeadowGiant()
{
int trail, caveEnter;
int fight1;
int loot;
int goblinAttack, goblinHP, HP, attack, action1, ability; 
goblinAttack = 5;
goblinHP = 10;
HP = 100;

std::cout << -Insert story narrative- Choose a trail to go down.\n";
std::cin  >> trail; 

    if(trail==1)
    {
    std::cout << "-Insert story narrative- Come across a cave. Do you go in?\n";
    std::cin  >> caveEnter;

        if(caveEnter==1)
        {
        std::cout << "You are ambushed by a goblin. Run or fight?\n";
        std::cin >> fight1;

        goblinFight:
        loot = rand() % 4 + 1;
        srand(time(NULL));           

        if(fight1==1)
        {
        std::cout   << "Your HP: " << HP << std::endl;
        std::cout   << "Enemy HP: " << goblinHP << std::endl;
        std::cout   << "What do you do?\n
                    << "[1] Attack [2] Run \n";
        std::cin    >> action1;
        }
            if(goblinHP<=0)
            {
            std::cout << "You have slain the goblin!\n" 
                      << "You head towards the chest and take the spoils\n"
                      << "of battle!\n";
                 switch(loot)
            {
            case 1: std::cout << "You find a bastard sword!\n"
                              attack = attack + 7;
                              goto exitCave;
            case 2: std::cout << "You find an Enchanted Staff!\n"
                              attack = attack + 10;
                              goto exitCave;
            case 3: std::cout << "You find an Obsidian Dagger!\n"
                              attack = attack + 9;
                              goto exitCave;
            case 4: std::cout << "You find a Holy Mace!\n"
                              attack = attack + 10;
                              goto exitCave;
            }
    else if(action1==1)
    {
    std::cout   << "You successfully hit the goblin!\n"
                << "He strikes back!\n";
    attack = rand() % 10 + 1;  
    srand(time(NULL));

    goblinHP = goblinHP - attack;
    HP = HP - goblinAttack;
    goto goblinFight;
    }
    else if(action==2)
    {
    std::cout   << "You take the cowards way out and leave the cave.\n";
    goto exitCave;
    }
    }
else if(caveEnter==2)
{
exitCave:
std::cout << "You have exited the cave.\n";
} 
else
{
goto exitCave;
}
}
}
```

Here is the MeadowGiant.h for those who asked.

```
#define MEADOWGIANT_H

class MeadowGiant
{
public:
    MeadowGiant();
protected:
};

#endif`
#ifndef MEADOWGIANT_H
#define MEADOWGIANT_H

class MeadowGiant
{
public:
    MeadowGiant();
protected:
};

#endif
```

And this is all I'm really doing in main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "MeadowGiant.h"

int main()
{
MeadowGiant obj1;
}
```

Comment: To anyone who wants to help, it'd be awesome if you could run me through any corrections you made thoroughly. I don't have any teacher or peer than can help so you guys would be great to teach me what I did wrong and alternatives to doing so :)

Comment: More suited for [codereview.stackexchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: **If** this is migrated to Code Review, the title must describe the purpose of the code in brief, and the post body should describe the purpose of the code in detail. It'd also be nice if you could include the contents of `MeadowGiant.h`.

Comment: Added it, and sorry. New to the site!

Comment: I'd say use `for` loops and functions instead of `goto`s, but it kinda feels like I'm just saying it out of blind religion

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that really jumps out at me as a bad idea is the use of `goto`.  Inside a switch statement, for example, you case use `break` to jump out instead.

Comment: I'll definitely try that! Thanks for the quick reply. Now the other question I wanna ask is how do I make variables carry over class files? For example I have variables in ClassX.cpp that I want to work in ClassY.cpp with the same values that were in the previous class.

Comment: Lookup the extern keyword.  It makes global variables declared in one compilation unit visible from others.

Comment: I watched a ton of videos on using the extern function in C++ but I can't really grasp or understand how to use it. I have a variable in ClassX.cpp and want it used in main.cpp. Why does it have to be so difficult ;_;

Comment: In a nutshell, it's hard because C++ is compatible with C, which is a language where it's more important for the compiler to be easy to write than programs in the language.  The standards committee is working on modules to make things like this easier.  Until then, you should declare your global variable in ClassX.cpp, and declare it using the extern keyword in ClassX.h, then when you #include "ClassX.h" from main.cpp you can access it.

Comment: That almost got it working however I followed all your steps however in my ClassX.cpp I name an int global and in my ClassX.h I do as you said and name extern int global. I then go to my main.cpp and std::cout<<global but only and always get 0 printed out.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the input for a switch condition. What happen if someone press another key like "9" ? It would just skip the whole if condition part. Second                         `std::cin >> action1;` action1 is an integer, if someone enter a letter your programm will bug.

my recommended way to do that:

```
fail:char select = _getch() - '0';
                switch (select) {
                case 1: {....; break;}
                case 2: {....; break;}
                default: goto fail;
                }



 srand(time(NULL));  // <-- first the random seed
 attack = rand() % 10 + 1;  // <-- then the random function
```

Comment: I'd say use a `for` loop instead of `goto`, but it kinda feels like I'm just saying it out of blind religion

Answer (score 0):

```
else if(caveEnter==2)
{
exitCave:
std::cout << "You have exited the cave.\n";
} 
else
{
goto exitCave;
}
```

You can simplify this to

```
else {
exitCave:
    std::cout << "You have exited the cave.\n";
}
```

Also, using `goto` is not recommended. Inside `switch`, use `break`.